# kdb - How to pass a table by reference to kdb function

Tags: kdb

### Define the question

Given an empty table `myt` defined by

```
myt:([] id:`int$(); score:`int$())
```

It is trivial to insert one or more records into it, for example

```
`myt upsert `id`score!1 100
```

But when it comes to defining a function to insert into a given table, it seems a different trick.

A first try version could be

```
upd:{[t] t upsert `id`score!42 314;} 

upd[myt]
```

Apparently it updates nothing to `myt` itself but a local copy version of it.

### Difficulties of Possible solutions

#### Possible solution 1: using the global variable instead

Let `myt` be a global variable, the variable will then be accessed inside a function.

```
upd:{`myt upsert `id`score!42 314;}

upd[]
```

It looks a good solution, expect if many `myt`s are required. Under this situation, one have to provide a lot of copy for `upd` function as following

```
upd0:{`myt0 upsert `id`score!42 314;}
upd1:{`myt1 upsert `id`score!42 314;}
upd2:{`myt2 upsert `id`score!42 314;}
...
```

So, the global variable solution is not a good solution here.

#### Possible solution 2: amending table outside function

One can also solve the problem by amending `myt` just outside the function, returning the modified result by removing the ending `;`.

```
upd:{[t] t upsert `id`score!42 314}  / return inserted valued

myt:upd[myt]
```

It works! But after running this code for millions of times, it works slower and slower. Because this solution discards the "in-place" property of `upsert` operator, the copy overhead increases as the size of table getting larger.

### Pass argument by reference?

Maybe the concept of "pass-by-reference" solution here. Or maybe q has its own solution for this problem and I have not get the essential idea.

## [UPDATE] Solved by adding "`" to call-by-name

As cillianreilly answers, it is simple to add a "`" symbol in front of `myt` to declare it as a global variable when pass it into function. So the perfect solution is direct.

```
upd:{[t] t upsert `id`score!42 314;} 

upd[`myt] / it works
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first version should achieve what you want. If you pass the table name as a symbol, it will update the global variable and return the table name. If you pass the table itself, it will return the updated table, which you can use in an assignment, as you found in possible solution 2. Note that the actual table will not have been updated by this operation.

```
q){[t;x]t upsert x}[myt;`id`score!42 314]
id score
--------
42 314
q)count myt
0
q){[t;x]t upsert x}[`myt;`id`score!42 314]
`myt
q)count myt
1
```

For possible solution 1, why would you need hundreds of myt tables? Regardless, there is no need to hardcode the table name into the function. You can just pass the table name as a symbol as demonstrated above, which will update the global for you. The official kx kdb tick example given on their github uses [insert](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/insert/) for exactly this scenario, but in practice a lot of developers use [upsert](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/upsert/). https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb-tick/blob/master/tick/r.q#L6

Hope this helps.